# Which Lightning wallets support splicing?

Tags: wallet, lightning-network, splicing

Which Lightning wallets support [splicing](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/splicing/) (the ability to add funds to payment channels)?

Comment: I believe the page you linked gives you the answer. Additionally, this is a question to which the answer will change frequently and so is not a good topic for this site.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad Are Core Lightning, Phoenix, and Eclair the only ones?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes. Additionally, [LDK](https://github.com/lightningdevkit/rust-lightning/issues/1621) is currently in the process of implementing it. I trust Bitcoin Optech to mention other wallets once they add splicing.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad Any GUI desktop clients support it?